# Group By Users and show DETAILED results for every week day

Tags: c#, linq

I have this situation.

Users schedule customer visits for a specific date. Eg.:
**USER1 is going to visit CUSTOMER1 on DATE1**

The model is something like this: |Customer|1 --- *| Visit |

The relevant model it's like this:

```
public class Visit
{
   public int VisitID { get; set; }
   public int User { get; set; }
   public int DateScheduled { get; set; }
   public int CustomerID { get; set; }
}
```

What i'm trying to do using LINQ and not a bunch of Lists and nested ForEach's is to show visit information grouped by USER, showing CUSTOMERS scheduled to visit by day in a certain period. I need to show information like this:

[image: Just like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work directly against the database because of the Date stuff, but something like this should work against an in-memory collection:

```
// Assuming Visits is an IEnumerable<Visit>
var userVisits = from v in Visits
                 group v by v.User into groupedVisits
                 select new { // AnonymousType1
                     User = groupedVisits.Key,
                     Visits = from gv in groupedVisits
                              group gv by gv.DateScheduled.Date into dateVisits
                              select new { // AnonymousType2
                                  DateScheduled = dateVisits.Key,
                                  Customers = from dv in dateVisits
                                              select dv.CustomerId
                              }
                 }
```

That would give you, essentially the following constructs:

```
class AnonymousType1
{
    public int User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AnonymousType2> { get; set; }
}

class AnonymousType2
{
    public DateTime DateScheduled { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

and `userVisits` would be an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType1>`

I'm not sure how you're going to avoid using some nested `foreach` statements in there to actually display the data. But this should give the data to you in a format that makes it easy to do so.

Note: I think some of those `IEnumerable<>` types I mention above might actually be `IQueryable<>` or similar. But this is pseudo code just to illustrate the rough structure of what you'd end up with by using a LINQ statement similar to the one above.

Comment: AWESOME. Thanks Tim, that solved my problem. The only thing i did was to type the anonymous types and everything works like a charm.

Comment: What if i want to count ALL Customers visited?. That would be make a COUNT of every `IENumerable<int> Customers` in AnonymousType2... How can i achieve that?